# ng-if, ng-switch and dynamic ng-include not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Basically I have a landing page that calls ng-repeat and displays a list of data from a json file which populates some dynamic includes.  Each list item has a link that all go to the same post.html page with the title coming from the JSON file.  On that same page I want to include a HTML partial based on the data from the JSON file.

The problem I am having is using ng-include with ng-if with the value from JSON file.  Both includes show though the expression is different and evaluate differently.

Some code snippets:

**app.js**

```
// Code goes here

/*global $:false, angular:false, applyResize:false, menu:false*/
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
(function() { //clousure

  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('site', ['ngRoute']),
    menu = {
      home: 'Home',
      angular: 'Angular'
    };

  /* CONFIG
    ===============================================================*/

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      })

    .when('/angular', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/angular.html',
      controller: 'postController'
    })

    .when('/blog/:id', {

      templateUrl: 'blog/post.html',
      controller: 'blogsController'
    })
  });


  /* CONTROLLERS
    =================================================================*/

  //Home/Main Controller
  app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', '$location', function($scope, $log, $location) {
    $log.info($location.path());
  }]);

  app.controller('MenuController', function() {
    this.product = menu;
  });

  app.controller('postController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/angular_posts.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.posts = data;
    });
  }]);

  //Blog Controller
  app.controller('blogsController', ['$scope', '$log', '$location', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $log, $location, $http,  $routeParams) {
    $http.get('data/angular_posts.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.post = data[$routeParams.id];
    });

    $scope.x = "true";
  }]);


  /* DIRECTIVES
    =================================================================*/

  app.directive('menuDirective', [])
    .directive('myMenu', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'directives/menu.html',
        scope: {
          menuName: "@"
        }
      };
    });
}());
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Animations in Angular - Part 1",
        "summary": "Getting started with Angular Animations is relatively simple.  So let's take a look at a simple example to get you started.",
        "article": "yes",
        "url": "blog/angular/angular_blog1.html",
        "index": "0"

    },
    {
        "title": "Angular 2.0 - What you need to know",
        "summary": "Work in progress!",
        "article": "yes",
        "url": "blog/angular/angular_blog1.html",
         "index": "1"

    }
]
```

**post.html**

```
   <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>

<input ng-model="index" value={{post.index}} hidden>

{{post.index==0}}

<div ng-if='"{{post.index == 0}}"'>
    {{post.index==0}} **//Evaluates to True**
    <div ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog1.html'"></div>
</div>
<div ng-if='"{{post.index == 1}}"'>
   {{post.index==1}} **//Evaluates to False**
    <div ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog2.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Even though one evaluates to true and the other evaluates to false both includes are shown.  Any ideas?

http://embed.plnkr.co/qiTkUI/preview

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649617/angularjs-change-partial-in-controller-on-click)

Comment: Had a look at the example and ng-switch could be what I am looking for however the example is a bit different as my click leads to a new route with dynamic title so the content would be loaded together rather than that example.  Thank you though I will see if I can get it to work for me:)

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it's a little clearer.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. You're saying you want to include an html partial into `post.html` and you did so in your code with `ng-switch`. But you're still not happy. But why, what is it that you're trying to achieve, _exactly_?

Comment: @frhd the ng-switch isn't working as I would like possible do to a scope issue.  As it is dependent on the value from the JSON file in the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution:

I was trying to do this:

```
  <ng-switch on="'{{post.index}}'">

    <ng-switch-when="0" ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog' + {{post.index}} + '.html'">

    <ng-switch-when="1" ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog' + {{post.index}} + '.html'">

  </ng-switch>
```

Changed to this:

```
<ng-switch on="'{{post.index}}'">

    <ng-switch-when="0" ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog' + post.index + '.html'">

    <ng-switch-when="1" ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog' + post.index + '.html'">

  </ng-switch>
```

Works but getting a 404 error: GET http://127.0.0.1:59077/blog/angular/angular_blog.html 404 (Not Found)

Will update the answer once I have figured it out. Thanks

**UPDATE: WORKING SOLUTION WITH NO ERRORS**

```
<div ng-if="post.index">
  <ng-switch on="post.index">

    <ng-switch-when="'0'" ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog' + post.index + '.html'">

    <ng-switch-when="'1'" ng-include="'blog/angular/angular_blog' + post.index + '.html'">

  </ng-switch>
</div>
```